# Efficient way to Calculate h-index (impact/productivity of author publication) in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I'm very new to pandas, but I've been reading about it and how much faster it is when dealing with big data.

I managed to create a dataframe, and I now have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
    0     1
0    1    14
1    2    -1
2    3  1817
3    3    29
4    3    25
5    3     2
6    3     1
7    3    -1
8    4    25
9    4    24
10   4     2
11   4    -1
12   4    -1
13   5    25
14   5     1
```

`Columns 0` is author's id and `column 1` is the number of citations this author had on a publication (-1 means zero citations). Each row represents a different publication for an author.

I'm trying to calculate the `h-index` for each of these authors. `h-index` is defined as the number of h publications the author has that are cited at least h times. So for authors:

> author 1 has h-index of 1
>
> author 2 has h-index of 0
>
> author 3 has h-index of 3
>
> author 4 has h-index of 2
>
> author 5 has h-index of 1

This is the way I am currently doing it, which involves a lot of looping:

```
current_author=1
hindex=0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0]==current_author:
        if row[1]>hindex:
            hindex+=1
    else:
        print "author ",current_author," has h-index:", hindex
        current_author+=1
        hindex=0
        if row[1]>hindex:
            hindex+=1
            
print "author ",current_author," has h-index:", hindex
```

My actual database have over 3 million authors. If I loop for each one this will take days to calculate. I'm trying to figure out what you think is the fastest way to tackle this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I renamed your columns to 'author' and 'citations' here, we can groupby the authors and then apply a lambda, here the lambda is comparing the number of citations against the value, this will generate a 1 or 0 if true, we can then sum this:

```
In [104]:

df['h-index'] = df.groupby('author')['citations'].transform( lambda x: (x >= x.count()).sum() )
​
df
Out[104]:
    author  citations  h-index
0        1         14        1
1        2         -1        0
2        3       1817        3
3        3         29        3
4        3         25        3
5        3          2        3
6        3          1        3
7        3         -1        3
8        4         25        2
9        4         24        2
10       4          2        2
11       4         -1        2
12       4         -1        2
13       5         25        1
14       5          1        1
```

**EDIT** As pointed out by @Julien Spronck the above doesn't work correctly if for author 4 they had citations 3,3,3. Normally you cannot access the inter group index but we can compare the citation value against the `rank`, this is a pseudo index but it only works if the citation values are unique:

```
In [129]:

df['h-index'] = df.groupby('author')['citations'].transform(lambda x: ( x >= x.rank(ascending=False, method='first') ).sum() )
​
df
Out[129]:
    author  citations  h-index
0        1         14        1
1        2         -1        0
2        3       1817        3
3        3         29        3
4        3         25        3
5        3          2        3
6        3          1        3
7        3         -1        3
8        4         25        2
9        4         24        2
10       4          2        2
11       4         -1        2
12       4         -1        2
13       5         25        1
14       5          1        1
```

Comment: Thank you both! I actually went ahead and compared the timings of both codes, I found that @JulienSpronck's runs nearly twice as fast. Could it be that cause he uses mostly numpy as opposed to the actual pandas dataframe? I'm curious as I'm trying to learn, and I thought Pandas was supposed to help me save time. I do know that it is built on Numpy though.

Comment: It depends on how you're timing it and also the size of the data, I would expect that as my method is perform fewer ops it should scale better but there shouldn't be a huge difference, when performing pure math operations then it can be faster using np operations but it depends on the type of operation

Comment: thanks @EdChum :) I just put a timeit.timer() before and after each one and subtracted the time. What your saying makes sense as I am dealing with big data.

Comment: Also be careful with timings, I normally use `timeit` which is built into ipython but can be imported as a module, this typically runs the code multiple times, sometimes 100s or 1000s of times and picks the best average times, the reason to do this is to factor out any caching that maybe skewing the timings

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is fast enough but here is a solution that should work for you. In this code, I first sort the data frame by author and then by decreasing citation number. I add a column with a new index corresponding to the paper number for each author. I create another column by comparing the paper number to the citation number. All is left to do is to sum that last column per author.

```
import numpy as np

df2 = df.sort([0,1],ascending=[1,0])
groups = df2.groupby(0)
ind2 = np.array([np.arange(len(g))+1 for g in groups.groups.itervalues()])
df2['newindex'] = np.hstack(ind2)
df2['condition'] = df2[1]>=df2['newindex']
hindex = df2.groupby(0).sum()['condition']

## 0
## 1    1
## 2    0
## 3    3
## 4    2
## 5    1
```

Comment: I tried running it. hindex only returns a dataframe filled with True. Also the ones with -1 should be taken into consideration as they have an hindex of 0.

Comment: Thanks Julien. The code I have above actually does work, the logic is correct (dont know if that helps). I just feel it's really slow and that I'm not really utilizing Pandas as I should.

Comment: @BKS I think I fixed it and the code should now work ... let me know if this is faster or not

Comment: @BKS you're welcome ... if it works, do you mind up-voting for the effort?

Comment: It won't let me :( I think it's cause I'm new on stackoverflow. (rep = 9)